# Selecting IP that appears more than 3 times

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table that looks like this

```
  id             ip
------        ---------
  1              192.212.1.1
  2              192.212.1.1
  3              156.232.1.1
  4              192.212.1.1
  5              192.212.1.1
  6              561.235.2.1
  7              156.261.2.2
```

So far I've tried this query

```
SELECT ip FROM voluum_clicks HAVING COUNT(ip) > 3;
```

What I need it to return is

```
  id             ip
------        ---------
  1              192.212.1.1
  2              192.212.1.1
  4              192.212.1.1
  5              192.212.1.1
```

Comment: You are missing `GROUP BY ip`

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT * FROM voluum_clicks where ip in
    (SELECT ip FROM voluum_clicks group by ip HAVING COUNT(ip) > 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
    id, 
    ip
from voluum_clicks 
where ip in
(
    SELECT 
        ip 
    FROM voluum_clicks 
    GROUP by ip
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 3
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Ip 
FROM voluum_clicks v1 
WHERE (SELECT Count(*) FROM volumm_clicks v2 WHERE v2.Ip = v1.Ip) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use count as below:

```
Select Id, [Ip] from (
    Select *, count([id]) over(partition by [Ip]) as RCnt from #ipdata
    ) a Where a.RCnt >= 3
```

Output as below:

```
+----+-------------+
| Id |     Ip      |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 192.212.1.1 |
|  2 | 192.212.1.1 |
|  4 | 192.212.1.1 |
|  5 | 192.212.1.1 |
+----+-------------+
```